# Rails 2.3 and rspec-rails compatability

Tags: compatibility, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

What version of the `rspec-rails` gem is still compatible with Rails 2.3 branch (2.3.14 specifically)? I've tried `2.1.0`, but that one's also for Rails >= 3.0. Any other dependencies or version limitations that I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: I've answered below, but obviously you should try to upgrade Rails first. There have been many changes between RSpec 1 and RSpec 2, you will fight an uphill battle trying to get it all working, and you will lock yourself into a legacy version. But RSpec 1 is for Rails 2, RSpec 2 is for Rails 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Version 1.3.4 is the latest supported version for Rails 2.x.

http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails/versions/1.3.4

Comment: How did you determine this?  Is there a chart somewhere that lists rspec versions and supported rails versions?

Comment: No chart, I just went through the RSpec versions on rubygems.org and looked at the Runtime Dependencies.