# Rails 2 and unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm going to be working on upgrading a Rails 2 app to Rails 3. The app currently has no test coverage.

It's unclear to me if rspec-rails has a version that is compatible with Rails 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Use this for rails 2.x.x https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails. This gem is compatible with rails 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274329/rails-2-3-and-rspec-rails-compatability